# Correct use of Modernizr.prefixed with transition and transform on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, modernizr

I have a function which animates elements on page. It adding inline style to this element. In the simplest situation it adds those:

```
<div style="transition: transform 0.5s; transform: translateX(100px);">...</div>
```

But i want to add support for older browsers so i used `Modernizer.prefixed` to find correct prefixes for properties, but now I have problem with Safari.

I try to use this code:

```
var cssTransformProperty = Modernizr.prefixed("transform");
var cssTransitionProperty = Modernizr.prefixed("transition");
$myElement
    .css(cssTransitionProperty, cssTransformProperty + " 0.5s")
    .css(cssTransformProperty, "translateX(" + margin + "px)");
```

but on safari it trying to add something like this:

```
.css("transition", "WebkitTransform 0.5s")
.css("WebkitTransform", "translateX(100px)")
```

Problem is here: `"WebkitTransform 0.5s"` - Safari don't understand this line. If I changing it manualy to `"-webkit-transform 0.5s"` it works as expected.

Is there a way to tell prefixer to use this css format instead of js one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, as the [Modernizr docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/) pointed out:

> Return values will also be the camelCase variant, if you need to translate that to hyphenated style use:

```
str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(str,m1){ return '-' + m1.toLowerCase(); }).replace(/^ms-/,'-ms-');
```

Example:

```
var str = Modernizr.prefixed('WebkitTransform'); 
str = str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(str,m1){ return '-' + m1.toLowerCase(); }).replace(/^ms-/,'-ms-'); 
alert(str); //-webkit-transform
```